# Where can I see positions and companies I have applied to?

Tags: support, jobs

I am not able to find on my Careers profile the positions I applied to in the past. Is there a way to see positions I have previously applied to?

I've sent in applications to around 8-10 positions in the last month or so and would like to be able to check or track which companies and/or positions I've already applied for.

Comment: Related: [mark jobs as applied](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/129957/a-way-to-mark-jobs-as-applied-for-that-dont-have-an-apply-button), even if you do it outside the SO Careers form.

Answer (score 10):

If you click on the messages link near the top right corner of the page you'll find your messages and a list of your job applications.

> [image]

And then:

> [image]

Comment: To be fair, it's not obvious... and that's why I'm working on it right now!

Comment: Yeah, I applied to something today and someone challenged me to find a list of things I've applied to. I couldn't. That's a _weird_ place to put the list, I more expected to see it (or links to get to it) upon clicking my name.

Comment: The exchange is in the TL if you want to read it.

Comment: Please edit the answer to messages in `top right corner`. Even after this answer I could not find it. Actually I kind of accidentally stumbled into it.

Comment: @palerdot when in doubt, add screenshots with FHRC. ;)

Comment: @Jason, This doesn't work for many companies since you get redirected to an external site after clicking "Apply Now" button. E.g. https://careers.stackoverflow.com/jobs/98876/application-security-engineer-rockstar-games

Comment: @Pacerier: Yes. Those companies don't accept applications via email or an ATS integration. We can't keep track of them. Sorry :(

Comment: What a poor user experience!!!  My applications are not available in the sent messages section.  I am unable to find the original job application description... please tell me this is just "newbie error".

Comment: @JasonPunyon, Btw just curious: most of the applications I see link to external sites. Is this just me or is it that a fairly high percentage of companies are doing it without integration?

Comment: Pay attention to the detail "SENT", no inbox.