# A way to mark jobs as applied for that don't have an apply button

Tags: feature-request, jobs

Marking jobs as applied for is great. It would be better if you could manually mark jobs as applied to for ones that don't have an apply button but list an email address instead.

Possibly related to [Where can I see positions and companies I have applied to?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/121678/stackoverflow-careers-positions-i-applied-to).

Comment: Additionally, it would be nice if you could mark jobs as applied for that have an apply button, but it sends you to some other site to apply.