# Can a "mark applied" option be added to the Careers site?

Tags: feature-request, jobs

Employers can apparently set up the posting so that applying is external to the site (i.e. "email us here" instead of clicking the button).  This is fine, except that then the site loses track of whether an application was made.  Please add a "mark applied" option for such postings so that the same designation can be applied to those listings manually.

Comment: Amen. I was literally about to post this identical feature request.

Comment: Duplicate of https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/129957/a-way-to-mark-jobs-as-applied-for-that-dont-have-an-apply-button